i want to pass all list after doing the post operation in Ajax
***I am trying to pass a list from controller to ajax in success. Its a post request from ajax. ***
When I am trying it comes as [model model]
*This my controller
public JsonResult CreatePackage(string Package)
{
    new ProductQueries().InsertTable("Packages", _DataBaseName, Package);
    List<Packages> packages = new ProductQueries().GetPackageTable("Packages", _DataBaseName);
   
    return Json(packages);
}

**This is my ajax please can someone let me know what I am doing wrong. Using after ages bit rusty on it any help is appreciated**


function CreatePackage() {
     var Package = $('#Package').val();
     $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         dataType: 'JSON',
         url: '@Url.Action("CreatePackage", "Product")',
         data: { Package },
         success:
             function (data) {
                 console.log(data);
                 debugger;
                 $.each(data, function (key, item) {
                     $("DropDownList").append('< label class="dropdown-option" ><input type="checkbox" name = "dropdown-group" value = "' + key+ '" />' + item+ '< /label>');
                 });
             }
     });
 }

**This is my model**
 public class Packages
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Package { get; set; }
 }


"it comes as [model model]": How did you determine this?  What * should* it come as?

"it comes as [model model]" - Be specific.  Which exact operation in the code shown is producing this result, and is this the exact output it produces?

i want to use in loop $("DropDownList").append('< label class="dropdown-option" >' + item+ '< /label>');op

@David function CreatePackage()  it comes in this and i have mention it on the very beginning *pass a list from controller to ajax in success. *

@RajatBhandwalkar: "it comes in this" - That function produces output in multiple places.  Is the console.log statement producing the output you describe?  Something else?  Be specific.

You're returning a list of objects:
List<Packages> packages = //...
return Json(packages);

Then looping over that list:
$.each(data, function (key, item) {

And trying to render an object as a string:
'<label class="dropdown-option"><input type="checkbox" name="dropdown-group" value="' + key + '" />' + item + '</label>'

But an object isn't a string.  It's an object.  What string value would you expect it to render as and why?
Your object has two properties:
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Package { get; set; }

Are you intending to use the Package property in your output?  If so then use that property:
'<label class="dropdown-option"><input type="checkbox" name="dropdown-group" value="' + key + '" />' + item.package + '</label>'

(Note: It may be item.package or item.Package depending on your JSON serialization settings.)
It also seems likely that you probably want to use item.id instead of key, since key is an otherwise meaningless array index:
'<label class="dropdown-option"><input type="checkbox" name="dropdown-group" value="' + item.id + '" />' + item.package + '</label>'

(Note: It may be item.id or item.Id depending on your JSON serialization settings.)
Basically, the system has no way of knowing how you want your object to be represented as a string.  You have to specify that when outputting it.

Thank you so much i knew i was close. just a small question what is key used for what does it hold

@RajatBhandwalkar: Have you checked the documentation as well as used a debugger to understand and observe the value of key?  That's often the best place to start.  When you do that, if something isn't working as expected or if you have a specific problem or question about the observed result then that may make for a new Stack Overflow question.  Be sure to include in that question a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem and the specific observation you are making and question you are asking.
